# Framework To Turn My Python Email Crawler Into Web Application

Tags: python

After a couple years of being decently experienced in Python, I just learned that it's used in web development. I have made an email crawler program (basically a function that uses several other functions) in Python that helps the company I'm interning at generate leads. My boss asked if I could somehow make my python email crawler into a web application so other employees could crawl emails instead just me doing it, so I can work on more important things.

Are there are web application frameworks out there that I can use to turn my python email crawler program into a simple and company private web application? And what's a general ball-park time range that it would take to make the web application?

I'm very open and eager to learning web application development, so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django is the way to go if you are experienced with python. Depending on your experience/time it could take you anywhere from a few days to a few weeks to get it up and running. But, it's a very useful web framework and there's a ton of documentation online and support on stackoverflow. Here's a tutorial:
https://www.djangoproject.com/

Comment: I've heard Django mentioned before by web developers but never knew it was Python oriented. But wow, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! :)